# Object.get() throws exception if Nothing is found

Tags: python, django

Is there a possibility to return none if no results are found by a `object.get()` function call?
I know it throws an exception by default, but I want to return none from it.

Comment: Use `filter(<conditions>).first()`, it returns `None` if nothing is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with exceptions like:

```
 try:    
     object = Model.objects.get(foo='bar') 
 except Model.DoesNotExist:    
     object = None
```

Comment: You can even override `def get(self)` in your custom ModelManager to change that behavior.